# highcharts, skipping dates

Tags: json, highcharts

I load data to chart from json file.
The charts looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jk171505/zC9dP/1/

Is there a way to 'simplify' displayed data, something like an average?

```
       xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        maxZoom: 48 * 3600 *1000
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look there are any averaging functions in the highcharts API. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts
So you will probably have to pre-process that data yourself to get an average. On your jsfiddle you have an object with an array of data. Here is how you could loop through to get the average of the entire set.

```
var sum = 0;
dataObj.series[0].data.forEach(function(point){
 sum += point[1]
});
var average = sum/dataObj.series[0].data.length;
```

If you want to keep the original data set and just manipulate the values, you can also loop through and modify every single value.

```
dataObj.series[0].data.forEach(function(point){
 point[1] = average;
});
```

I don't know too much about your application, but you probably don't want to get the average of the entire set, or change every point in the set to the same value. So you should break the set up into chunks and get averages per chunk to graph it that way. Be creative based on your application, but it looks like you will have to pre-process your data.